# Best way to build native app for mobile (iOS, Android, ...) using already AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I built an AngularJS application using few plugins such as angular ui-router, angular-translate... and bootstrap 3.

It works for web browser of desktop/laptop. Smartphone with built-in web browser works fine too but I think it's not good enough (battery issue...). So now I need to build native app for mobile OS such as iOS or Android.

So which is best way (may use framework or something like that) to build native app with lowest cost (because AngularJS app is already)? If I have to write native app for each mobile OS from scratch, it may consume much time. Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you've ever looked at the Ionic Framework, but that sounds up your street. http://ionicframework.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web technologies to create mobile application [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

So you can turn your `AngularJS` application into mobile app

Comment: It sounds good. I'll dig into it. But now can you introduce me some info? For instance, server returns 'index.html' when client connects to server, so 'index.html' for desktop/laptop and mobile are the same or not?